# Integral of symbolic expression on one of 2 variables

Tags: matlab

I have a function defined like this:

```
syms t;
syms y;
x(t,y) = t*y;
```

Now I want to know the integral of this symbolic expression, by fixing y as a constant, from 0 to inf.

is there a way to do this using a symbolic expression, containing 2 variables? So I can have a symbolic expression only depending of one variable.

Comment: According to [the documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/int.html) you just need to specify the variable of integration.

Comment: thx I was using integral!! I didn't know about the function you gave, you can post it as answer, I'll accept it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You almost have it already. As suggested by Michael Burr. If you want to solve an integral using MATLAB, you need to use `int(expr,var)`, which would be `int(t*y,y)` for your case. More information is located in the [documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/int.html).